# Email grouped array results

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

So I've got a series of arrays that look like this:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[214]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'data' => string 'test'
          'user' => string 'testmail@testing.com'
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[215]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'data' => string 'Awesome test' 
          'user' => string 'tester@mail.com'
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[220]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'data' => string ' A string' 
          'user' => string 'different.tester@mail.com'
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'data' => string 'Another string again' 
          'user' => string 'different.tester@mail.com'
```

I'm wanting to loop through each array and send the data values to the relevant user.

So different.tester@mail.com would receive 'A string' and 'Another string again' for example.

I'm totally stuck on this and would welcome any feedback!

Thanks

Comment: Fixed the issue! Was a simple case of looping through the arrays.